# how to merge two dataframes and sum the values of columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-analysis

I have two dataframes

```
df1
Name class value
Sri   1     5
Ram   2     8
viv   3     4

df2
Name class value
Sri   1     5
viv   4     4
```

My desired output is,

```
df,

Name class value
Sri   2     10
Ram   2     8
viv   7     8
```

Please help, thanks in advance!

Comment: Here you are only mentioning the requirements, did you try something?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I think need [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) for both `DataFrame`s, [`add`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.add.html) and last [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html):

```
df = df1.set_index('Name').add(df2.set_index('Name'), fill_value=0).reset_index()
print (df)
  Name  class  value
0  Ram    2.0    8.0
1  Sri    2.0   10.0
2  viv    7.0    8.0
```

If values in `Name` are not unique use `groupby` and aggregate `sum`:

```
df = df1.groupby('Name').sum().add(df2.groupby('Name').sum(), fill_value=0).reset_index()
```

Comment: I am getting `UserWarning: Boolean Series key will be reindexed to match DataFrame index.` what to do

Comment: @chandru - Can you check if duplicated index?

Comment: @chandru - Also what is your pandas version?

Comment: that was a warning, actually I am getting `pandas.core.indexing.IndexingError: Unalignable boolean Series key provided` my `pandas version is 0.19.2`

Comment: @chandru - Is possible upgrade pandas?

Comment: sorry, I am afraid my other programs and functioins will work properly after updating

Comment: @chandru - Are data confidental?

Comment: Just to add to your answer, if you already have an index on both `DataFrame`, you can just do `df=df1.add(df2, fill_value=0)`.

Answer (score 8):

#### [`pd.concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) + [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) + `sum`

You can concatenate your individual dataframes and then group by your key column:

```
df = pd.concat([df1, df2])\
       .groupby('Name')['class', 'value']\
       .sum().reset_index()

print(df)

  Name  class  value
0  Ram      2      8
1  Sri      2     10
2  viv      7      8
```