# How to add multiple dataframes together

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I would like to add multiple data frames together, with differing columns, but if there are similar columns/cells, then the values will be added together.

Here is an example:

Input:

df1

| Region Code (Index) | Number of police stations | Amount of crime | Average Age |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| B | 2 | 2 | 35 |
| A | 1 | 5 | 45 |
| C | 3 | 5 | 56 |

df2

| Region Code (Index) | Number of police stations | Amount of crime |
| --- | --- | --- |
| B | 5 | 2 |
| A | 3 | 5 |

Expected output:

| Region Code (Index) | Number of police stations | Amount of crime | Average Age |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| B | 7 | 4 | 35 |
| A | 4 | 10 | 45 |
| C | 3 | 5 | 56 |

Any indication of how to do it or maybe a better way to structure would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Your question appears to be missing some details in `df2`

Comment: Please refer here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49111859/how-to-merge-two-dataframes-and-sum-the-values-of-columns

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas DataFrame merge summing column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23361218/pandas-dataframe-merge-summing-column)

Comment: hi @mujjiga not exactly, the actual dataframe is much more complex than that, I will close this question and re-ask with more context, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try this using `pd.concat` to join the 2 `dataframe`. Then `groupby` the `Region Code (Index)` and aggregate `column` by `sum`

```
df = pd.concat([df1,df2])
df = df.groupby(by="Region Code (Index)", as_index=False).agg({"Number of police stations":"sum", "Amount of crime":"sum", "Average Age":"sum"}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `concat` and `groupby` with `sum`:

```
pd.concat([df1, df2]).groupby('Region Code (Index)', as_index=False, sort=False).sum()
```

---

```
  Region Code (Index)  Number of police stations  Amount of crime  Average Age
0                   B                          7                4         35.0
1                   A                          4               10         45.0
2                   C                          3                5         56.0
```

I added `sort=False` to keep the order, `B` `A` `C`.

Answer (score 0):

you can use  `pd.concat`

```
result = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1, join="inner")
```